# What is the purpose of delayed suspend (Ctrl-Y) in Bash?

Tags: bash, signals, job-control, jobs

The full portion of the Bash man page which is applicable only says:

> If the operating system on which bash is running supports job control, bash contains
>          facilities to use it.  Typing the suspend character (typically ^Z, Control-Z)  while
>          a  process is running causes that process to be stopped and returns control to bash.
>          **Typing the delayed suspend character (typically ^Y, Control-Y) causes the process to
>          be  stopped  when  it  attempts  to  read input from the terminal, and control to be
>          returned to bash.**  The user may then manipulate the state of this job, using the `bg`
>          command to continue it in the background, the `fg` command to continue it in the foreground, or the kill command to kill it.  A ^Z takes effect immediately, and has  the
>          additional side effect of causing pending output and typeahead to be discarded.

I have never used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>; I only just learned about it.  I have done fine with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> (suspend) only.

I am trying to imagine what this option is *for*.  When would it be useful?

(Note that this feature doesn't exist on all Unix variants. It's present on [Solaris](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=termio&sektion=7I&manpath=SunOS+5.10) and OpenBSD but not on Linux or FreeBSD. The corresponding setting is `stty dsusp`.)

Perhaps less subjectively: Is there anything that can be accomplished with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> that cannot be accomplished just as easily with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>?

Comment: @Gilles, though FreeBSD seems to have a `stty dsusp`, I've not managed to make it send a SIGTSTP upon ^Y (I did on Solaris). Have you?

Comment: It's in `termios`, but FreeBSD's line discipline does not do anything special in response to the character.  OpenBSD's line discipline does, however.

Comment: dsusp didn't make it through the FreeBSD tty layer rewrite from 2008: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/cc3116a

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [4BSD manual for csh](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4BSD/usr/man/cat1/csh.1):

> A `^Z` takes effect immediately and is like an interrupt in that pending output and unread input are discarded when it is typed.  There is another special key `^Y` which does not generate a STOP signal until a program attempts to *read*(2) it.  This can usefully be typed ahead when you have prepared some commands for a job which you wish to stop after it has read them.

So, the purpose is to type multiple inputs while the first one is being processed, and have the job stop after they are done.

Comment: This description is subtly different from the bash manual.  *"...does not generate a STOP signal until a program attempts to read **it.**"*  It sounds like everything in the input stream *up to* the `^Y` will be read successfully, and then when the `^Y` is hit the process will be stopped.  Am I reading this right?

Comment: @Wildcard in my test on Mac OS X, the process is stopped before read() returns (but after the call to read() that _would have_ returned the Y runs), and after it is resumed it receives the input from before ^Y. I think as this was intended to be used, though, it would be used at the start of a line, so the behavior in this case would not matter. I suspect that in the actual code, it is suspended when the ^Y would have been copied into the user process read buffer.

Comment: I was right, in the [original BSD kernel's ttread function](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.3BSD-Tahoe/usr/src/sys/sys/tty.c) you can see this, and [modern OSX](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.60.10/bsd/kern/tty.c)

Comment: But, when the process is resumed, the call will succeed and will contain the data you typed into your terminal before `^Y`, even if you have disowned the process and closed your terminal before the process is resumed.  Right?  (*"...after it is resumed it receives the input from before ^Y."*  That's what I meant; I don't usually deal in C code.)  :)

Comment: Yes. And it returns without a newline at the end, which is unusual for a read in canonical mode [similar to if you'd typed some text and then pressed ^D once] I suspect they didn't think about this case very much, since it's really intended to be typed at the start of a line.

Answer (score 13):

Say there's a loop reading input and executing. It may be useful to let the task finish the current instruction it computes, without interrupting it before it gets back to the command line for a new one. So thus to end a cycle. This ends the loop gracefully and prevents it from running again if `read` is under a timeout restriction.

Comment: But if it's going to try to read input from the terminal anyway, it will *stop* at that point (and wait for your input), and you can `^Z` it *then*.

Comment: Yes. See update.

Comment: Check one more. @Wildcard

Comment: I think the "read" being under a timeout restriction is the only plausible use case, actually.  Are there any common commands that actually have such a timeout?

Comment: `read` itself: `read -t 1`

Comment: But if it's got a timeout, wouldn't it also just end gracefully if you did nothing special?

Comment: It might. But it might also go on and do some default job.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of one scenario where it might be useful, but it's something of a contrived edge-case.

Suppose you're debugging a script that is writing temporary files that you wish to analyze before they're deleted as part of a clean-up routine.

You could add a `read foo` somewhere after the files are written (but before the cleanup), run the script, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> as they're being generated.  You will then be dropped to a prompt with the script suspended in the background to do whatever you need to do, and can then `fg` to allow the script to complete.

Comment: Seems unlikely, because the script will wait for input anyway.  So you could just as easily watch for it to prompt you for input and then suspend it with `^Z`.  In other words: after you type `fg` you will have to give the script some input *anyway* before it will continue.  Hence my question; I still don't see the point of `^Y`.  (Thanks for answering, though!)  :)

Answer (score 2):

The only scenario I can think of (and even I don't find it very convincing), is if you want to use some type-ahead for a shell command. Say some command is running which will read input some time in the future. Then you can ^Y it, and then immediately type the next shell command that you want to have executed when the running command suspends. I don't think I have ever really used this in several decades of using BSD Unix.