# What is the function of the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Y under Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, process, keyboard-shortcuts, signals

Below is excerpted from [a well-known professor's site](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html):

> Some signals cause a process to stop: SIGSTOP (stop!), SIGTSTP (stop
>   from tty: probably ^Z was typed), SIGTTIN (tty input asked by
>   background process), SIGTTOU (tty output sent by background process,
>   and this was disallowed by stty tostop).
>
> Apart from ^Z there also is ^Y. The former stops the process when it
>   is typed, the latter stops it when it is read.

I know what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> means under Linux, however, I don't know what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> does.

Any explanations?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303605/what-is-the-purpose-of-delayed-suspend-ctrl-y-in-bash

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Note that the question that you link to is not specific to Linux. On Linux, `Ctrl+Y` does not have the same function as described in the answers to that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ctrl-Y` isn't doing anything under Linux. `DSUSP` is not supported on Linux.

See the [man 3 termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) (emphasis mine):

`VDSUSP (not in POSIX; not supported under Linux; 031, EM, Ctrl-Y)
       Delayed suspend character (DSUSP): send SIGTSTP signal when
       the character is read by the user program.  Recognized when
       IEXTEN and ISIG are set, and the system supports job control,
       and then not passed as input.`

In the emacs mode of shell line editors and libraries like readline `Ctrl-Y` is bound to "yank" -- but that's a completely different thing: for instance, after deleting a word with `ESC-Backspace` you can reinsert it with `Ctrl-Y`.